# Dotted line changes to solid line when matlab fig save as .eps

Tags: eps, matlab

I have some matlab figures which I would like to put in a table in LaTeX (as shown in figure). The issue is, when I try to save my matlab figures as .eps and then try to insert in LaTeX, the dotted line change to dashed.

This is the code I am using:

```
 \begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|@{}}
  \hline
\textbf{Number of} & \textbf{Number of} & \textbf{Number of} \\
\textbf{Coefficients: 2} & \textbf{Coefficients: 3} & \textbf{Coefficients: 4}\\
  \hline
\textbf{Bifurcation Point: 1.56} & \textbf{Bifurcation Point: 1.74} & \textbf{Bifurcation Point: 1.76} \\
\hline
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Chapter2/NewFigs/2coff_a1_M5_twist2_linspace3And7_Finalfig.eps} &
    \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/figs_File/2coff_a2_M5_twist2_linspace3And7_Finalfig.eps} &
    \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-c} \\
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-c} \\
    \hline
    &  
     \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-c} \\
     \hline
     & & \includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is   some figure side by side}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

[image]

---

This is where I am trying to put the .eps figures:

[image: this is where i am trying to put .eps figs]

---

[image: this is where i am trying to put .eps figs]
this is where i am trying to put .eps figs

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can always use the "Edit" button to add more information to your question. I put the picture from your addition post to your question as well, since it is not really an answer to your question.